# enum exported from namespace in angular 6 causing runtime error

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, namespaces

Why enum exported from angular causing runtime error? Intellisense works fine but at runtime it cant find namespace wherever I used exported enum. But it works for exported interface from the namespace.

check this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enum-within-namespace

I have exported two entity from **User** namespace (file: user.ts)

```js
declare namespace User {
    export enum eUserType {
        Driver = 1,
        Passenger = 2,
        User = 3
    }

    export interface Profile {
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
    }
}
```

When trying to use it in AppComponent (file: app.component.ts)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    constructor() {
    this.displayUser();

    // uncommenting following piece of code is causing an error ... 
    // ==> this.displayUserType();
    }

    displayUserType() {
        const newVariable = User.eUserType.Driver;
        console.log(newVariable);
    }

    displayUser() {
        const profile = <User.Profile> {
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe"
        };
        console.log("profile:", profile);
    }
}
```

when you uncomment **this.displayUserType()** function you will see error in console ***User is not defined***

Answer (score 0):

You can change your namespace declaration to `export namespace User {...}` instead of `declare namespace User {...}` and then import it in your module like so:

`import { User } from './user'`

Here's your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enum-within-namespace-working) modified with a working example

Comment: I know that way it will work ... but it comes with limitation ... that I can't split the namespace between multiple files ... This is just an example but my namespaces is broken between around 6 different files ...